# Add external config files to jar using gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have couple external files that I want to add to my jar file and access those files within the class. I am running this jar file from command line using `java -jar` command. So when I use absolute path, I can access the file contents but when I use relative path I get `java.io.IOException: (No such file or directory)`. I have included both my files in `src/main/resorces` directory. I have tried using `file.conf, /file.conf, ./file.conf`, none of them worked. Also tried to include files in build.gradle
   `from{
      ["file1.conf","file2.conf"]
     }`.

Any idea how can I access file contents in my java code using relative path of the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to access files residing in the classpath. Those files will be packaged with your application and you know them by name. If this is right, and you don't specifically need a `java.io.File` but a way to accept the content of the file, I suggest this:

```
try (InputStream is = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/file.conf")) {
    // do something with the input stream
}
```

You can also retrieve a `java.net.URL` of your file, if you prefer.

Briefly, the syntax for the String attribute is a follows:

- If the attribute starts with `/`, the name is resolved from the root of the classpath. So for example, if you run `java -jar hello.jar`, file.conf has to be at the root of hello.jar
- If the attribute does not start with `/` then the name is resolved relatively to the class upon which you call the `getResourceAsStream()` method.

Check out the [Class API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) for more information.

Comment: I tried `URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("file.conf");` and `url.getPath()` but didn't worked. I still get `(No such file or directory)`. I do see my files at the root of the jar. It runs fine in Eclipse but not with `java -jar` command.

Comment: Did you try `URL url = MyClass.class.getResource("/file.conf");`

Comment: I created a properties file and it worked. But it didn't work with .conf file. So I printed the path of file.conf by `url.getPath()`. It shows something like `/Users/user/Desktop/workspace/project/build/libs/myProject-all-1.0.jar!/file.conf`. Is that ! after jar right? But when I print that path from Eclipse it shows the right path of the file, that is `../../Desktop/workspace/myProject/bin/file.conf`

Comment: The ! is fairly standard for a resource embedded in a JAR. It should be what you're aiming for. The path given by Eclipse refers to a resource outside a JAR.